# Cordova httpd local assets path

Tags: ios, cordova, localserver

I have an app that downloads html pages, css, js and images to its cordova.file.dataDirectory.
I have installed the httpd and the server is starting and running. But I do not seem to able to correctly target the files to display them.

How do I set the default directory to point to cordova.file.dataDirectory?

This does not work:

```
httpd.startServer({
 'www_root' : cordova.file.dataDirectory,
 'port' : 8080
}
```

Once I have started the server my goal is to display content like so:

```
<img src="http://path/named_folder/resource.jpg">
```

Or create a link like so:

```
<a href="http://path/named_folder/index.html">Link to resource</a>
```

But I cant seem to set the correct root path.
Currently the issue is in iOS but I will need to do the android path too

Comment: Should be localhost if you have a httpd server

Comment: Do you mean setting www_root as localhost like so?:

httpd.startServer({
 'www_root' : localhost,
 'port' : 8080
}

Trying to reference like this is not working:
<img src="http://localhost/named_folder/resource.jpg">